# Почему рекурсивная функция возвращает None

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

```
def re(s):
    if s > -1:
        s-=1
    if s<0:
        return s
    re(s)

print(re(10))
```

Вывод: None

Comment: Посмотрите [выполнение](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20re%28s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20s%20%3E%20-1%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s%20-%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20if%20s%20%3C%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20s%0A%20%20%20%20re%28s%29%0A%0Aprint%28re%282%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) по шагам, будет понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в том случае, когда не выполняется условие `s<0` функция ничего Не возвращает, иными словами возвращает `None`.

Попробуйте так:

```
def fun(s):
    if s > -1:
        s-=1
    if s<0:
        return s
    return fun(s)
```

Comment: То-есть функцию внутри себя надо вызывать исключительно через return?

Comment: если функция заканчивает свое выполнение без `return` , то она вернет `None`

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так

```
def re(s):
    if s > -1:
       s-=1
    return s
re(s)
```

Comment: Это не рекурсивная функция.