# Почему не срабатывает return в блоке if?

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Я пытаюсь разобраться в рекурсии и потому решаю задачу, где нужно равномерно распределить площадь земли на равные части. Код, вроде бы работает, но в последний момент он возвращает значение "I'm crazzzy" (я специально изменил стандартное None). Условие "width % length == 0" само-по себе должно выполняться, но это не так. Помогите понять почему.

```
def divide(width, length):
    print(width, length)
    #Делаем ширину больше, если это не так
    if width < length:
        width, length = length, width

    #Если ширина кратна длине, то возвращаем длину
    if (width % length == 0):
        return length
    #В ином случае вызываем функцию divide с новыми параметрами...
    else:
        divide(width - length*(width // length), length)

    #Почему это срабатывает? О_о?
    return 'I\'m crazzzzy'

print(divide(101, 10))
```

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999389/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-none)

Comment: Всё верно. Только я имею ввиду последний вызов функции, когда получается 10 % 1. Это же точно равно нулю. Но код из блока не выполняется.

Comment: замените: `divide(width - length*(width // length), length)` --> `return divide(width - length*(width // length), length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в тот момент когда срабатывает часть `else:` в условии:

```
else:
    divide(width - length*(width // length), length)
```

в стек попадает рекурсивный вызов `divide()`, после выхода из которого, закономерно выполнится:

```
return 'I\'m crazzzzy'
```

---

Решение: заменить:

```
else:
    divide(width - length*(width // length), length)
```

на:

```
else:
    return divide(width - length*(width // length), length)
```